# Change how URL appears in address bar through htaccess

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am trying to figure out if I can change how my URL appears in the address bar so, for example if I have: **www.example.com/123456789.php** I can change it so it appears as **www.example.com/file**

So far in my `.htaccess` file I have just this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule    ^file/?$    123456789.php    [NC,L]
```

This only works if I type in **www.example.com/file** but if I click a link to the page the URL still appears as **www.example.com/123456789.php**.

Is there a way I can make it that **www.example.com/123456789.php** will automatically change to **www.example.com/file** whenever it is opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that with an extra rule before above rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+123456789\.php([^\s?/]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /file [R=302,L]
```

This rule is using `THE_REQUEST` variable, that represents original request received by Apache from your browser. This variable doesn't change after execution of other rules as opposed to the `REQUEST_URI` variable.